# Using Thumbs_up to display users who voted on a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm using Thumbs_Up gem to let users vote on a post(called Topic). I've done the voting part but now I want to display the users who voted on that particular post. I'm very new to Ruby On Rails, and I'm stuck at the view part.

Here's my controller: app/controllers/topics_controller.rb

```
def vote_who
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @vote_list=@topic.voters_who_voted_for
end
```

In my index.html.erb, I want to display the names of there users who voted on that post. This should be right next to the vote button. Kind of like this,

[image: index.html.erb view]

But how do I send back information from the controller? 
Or is this approach completely wrong?

Comment: By default each action in controller renders it's own template with same name. Instance variables defined in actions are then passed on to their templates. For details you should checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/. To show voters properly you need to post your views code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it's more preferable to show all voters in the 'show' view of the each particular Topic (imagine you have 100 voters for one topic, what this table in index view will look like?).

This way you don't need any distinct action (due to Rails conventions 1 action == 1 view (in general)). Just put in your `show` action:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params [:id])
  @vote_list = @topic.voters_who_voted_for
end
```

Then in your view (`show.html.erb`) you need to do something like this:

```
<% @vote_list.each do |voter| %> 
  <%= voter.email %> #or login, or name, or any user's attribute you want to display in your list
<% end %>
```

Or even try to simplify this: leave `show` action in your `TopicsController` as it is (don't create any `@vote_list` variable, only find right Topic), and call `voters_who_voted_for` method inside your `show view`, e.g.:

```
<%= @topic.title %>
<%= @topic.body %>
<%= @topic.voters_who_voted_for %>
```

Comment: That's a nice way of fetching the voters right in the show view! And I was just wondering, in the controller, you don't have to explicitly pass "@vote_list" to the view? Is it automatically accessible in the show.html.erb? Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm pretty stuck at understanding how the controller and view are communicating with each other :/

Comment: Each instance of your Topic class can call the `voters_who_voted_for` method (because it's `acts_as_votable`). When you find topic by id (and save it in the @topic variable), it's already has all the methods of the Topic Class. Thanks to gem `voters_who_voted_for` is one of them.
Because Rails convention over configuration principles, all your data from actions in controllers are given to your views that have **the same** naming (#index - index.html.erb; #show - show.html.erb and so on, if you'll rename view (for example "indexes" not "index" it will know nothing about @topics variable).